# Maple : bug in EmpiricalDistribution?

Tags: probability, maple

Here are my first steps with the Maple Package "Statistics". This is Maple 2023 on Mac Intel.

I am trying to figure out what's wrong in the following code ... If someone can help, thank you very much !

```
with(Statistics);
law := EmpiricalDistribution([1, 2, 3], 'probabilities' = [1/3, 1/2, 1/6]);
X := RandomVariable(law);
Y := RandomVariable(law);

Probability(X = 1);
```

--> outputs 1/3 : ok

```
Probability({X = 1, Y = 1});
```

--> outputs 1/9 : ok

```
Probability(X + Y = 2);
```

--> outputs 0 : ** Not ok !**

Now, if I don't use EmpiricalDistribution but for example :

```
X := RandomVariable(Binomial(1, 1/2));
Y := RandomVariable(Binomial(1, 1/2));
```

it works well :

```
Probability(X + Y = 2);
```

--> outputs 1/4 : ok

Did I find a bug ? Or did I miss something ?

I tried to read the appropriate documentation, but EmpiricalDistribution is not enough documented IMHO, or maybe, as I wrote before, there is a bug in this function.

Comment: On the face of it, it looks like you're right, that there's an oversight or omission in EmpiricalDistribution. However, the people reading this forum are probably not the best audience to judge that -- I think you should take up the issue in a Maple-specific forum. I don't know where that might be, although a web search should find one.